# Replacing object in array - is it safe for Angular bindings

Tags: angularjs

I'm using Angular JS and I've implemented my form with a reset function.

- setPrimarySelectionEditEntry is called when I start editing the item on the form. primarySelectionEntry keeps the object that is bound to controls
- savePrimarySelectionEdit is called when user hits Save. What I do is I replace item in primarySelection array, as I use this array to display a list
- cancelPrimarySelectionEdit does nothing except setting the form to pristine state. Underlying array remains intact

  ```
  $scope.cancelPrimarySelectionEdit = function () {
      $scope.primarySelectionForm.$setPristine();
  };

  $scope.savePrimarySelectionEdit = function () {
      $scope.topicSelection.primarySelection[$scope.formEntryIndex] = $scope.primarySelectionEntry;
      $scope.cancelPrimarySelectionEdit();
  };

  $scope.setPrimarySelectionEditEntry = function (entry) {
      $scope.formEntryIndex = $scope.topicSelection.primarySelection.indexOf(entry); ;
      $scope.primarySelectionEntry = angular.copy(entry);
  };
  ```

It works: when I hit save item in the list reflects new values. When I hit cancel, then nothing happens. But I wonder if this replacing array item is safe in the context of angular?

Comment: Could you clarify the question? You say save works, in which case you don't seem to have a problem modifying your array since that is what it does, but then you ask if modifying an array works? Didn't you just see it work? Am I missing something?

Comment: My question is: will replacing object reference do not break angular's "machine", for instance bindings. To rehprase: it this the correct way of applying changes to model object. This is simple implementation of form's reset function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you change the model within [Angular's execution context](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#what-are-scopes_integration-with-the-browser-event-loop) it'll be safe to replace some elements or even the whole array. It won't break neither the data binding nor the event loop.

You only have to worry about changes done outside Angular's loop. For example, a DOM event listener in a directive. Let's say you have the following directive:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('resetForm', function(){
    return {
        link: function($scope, $iElement){
            //Add a listener to the element
            $iElement.on('click', function(){
                //Carefull: changes in scope in this context won't trigger an angular event loop.
                $scope.cancelPrimarySelectionEdit();
                //So, call $digest to process all the watchers
                $scope.$digest(); 
                return;
            });
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

Here, the `$scope.cancelPrimarySelectionEdit()` function can be called at any time, so a call to $scope.$apply() or $scope.$digest() should be added to tell Angular that something in the model has changed and needs to execute all the watchers from the current scope and its children.